# How to not show Google Ads for specific category posts in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't want to show google ads for specific category posts.

Which code would block show up google ads for specific category posts?
The google ads are located in content-single.php.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !is_category(1469) && !in_category(1469) ):
AD CODE GOES HERE
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [has_category()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category) function with "!" (logical not).

```
if( !has_category('category-to-exlude-slug') ) {
    //your google ads code
}
```